# Mongo return two lines instead one

Tags: mongodb

I'm having some problem with `$max` param in mongodb.

I would like to return just a max `uptime` value.

Query isolating a cenario:

```
db.monitoraservicos.aggregate([
{"$match" : {"instancia" : "bat1"}

},
{"$group": {"_id": {
                    "instancia": "$instancia",
                    "uptime" :  {"$max" :"$uptime"},
                    "time": "$time"
                    }
           }
},
{"$project" : {
                "instancia" : "$_id.instancia",
                "uptime" : "$_id.uptime",
                "time" : "$_id.time",
                "_id" : 0
            }
},
{"$sort" : {"instancia" : 1}}
        ])
```

Return :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "uptime" : 86,
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:37:37.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "uptime" : 221,
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:37:37.000Z")
}
```

What I expect :

```
   {
        "instancia" : "bat1",
        "uptime" : 221,
        "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:37:37.000Z")
    }
```

- I tried to put `$max` in `$project` too, and didn't work

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post a few sample documents of your collection?  I think that the problem lies within your $group stage, but would be able to help more if I can test locally.

Comment: Yes of course,  [here some example](https://github.com/paulocauca/mongodb_databasefiles/blob/master/monitoraservicos.json) , thank you !

Comment: @Cauca : It's because you're grouping not just on "instancia" but what actually you're doing here is a group on 'instancia + uptime + time' as a unique pair, Since your data set has two different uptime 86 & 221(instancia & time are same), you're getting 2records !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$max` **[accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#considerations)** not working inside **_id**, you need to write `$max` immediately under the `$group`

```
aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "instancia": "bat1"
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "instancia": "$instancia",
            "time": "$time"
        },
        "uptime": {
            "$max": "$uptime"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "instancia": "$_id.instancia",
        "uptime": "$uptime",
        "time": "$_id.time",
        "_id": 0
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "instancia": 1
    }
}])
```

Comment: I didn't know about that. Yes, it´s works :-) Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to see that! Also in this case you don't need to group with "instancia" because your match query says find only "bat1" values :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, also check my comment to know on what has gone wrong with your query :

```
db.monitoraservicos.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "instancia": "bat1" }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: '$instancia',
            uptime: { $max: "$uptime" },
            time: { $first: '$time' }
        }
    }, { $project: { uptime: 1, time: 1, instancia: '$_id', _id: 0 } }
])
```

or this is much better which might not need `$project` stage, it leaves an additional field `_id:''` in output, which can optionally be excluded in `$project`  :

```
db.monitoraservicos.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "instancia": "bat1" }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: '',
            uptime: { $max: "$uptime" },
            time: { $first: '$time' },
            instancia: { $first: '$instancia' }
        }
    }
])
```

If you've different timestamps then you need to do this :

```
db.monitoraservicos.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "instancia": "bat1" }

    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "instancia": "$instancia",
                "uptime": { "$max": "$uptime" },
                "time": "$time"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "instancia": "$_id.instancia",
            "uptime": "$_id.uptime",
            "time": "$_id.time",
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "uptime": -1 } }, { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Actually your dataset seems to have same time for all records matching to `{ "instancia": "bat1" }`, but in case if you've different date in time field for documents then first query will get you the value from first document it found in `$group` stage irrespective of whether that document's uptime is max value or not (time value can be from 86 as well), but second query should work fine, unless you've 221 in couple of documents, again where time is different for those - that case it would get time from first matching 221 document(altogether just to say, first query is best suitable in most cases).

Try & test on this dataset :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8ce9cf8efa15b6d2fc0179"),
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "servico" : "eal_server",
    "status" : "UP",
    "diahora" : "221d 12h",
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T19:36:37.000Z"),
    "uptime" : 21.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8ce9d08efa15b6d2fc017d"),
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "servico" : "eps_server",
    "diahora" : "221d 12h",
    "status" : "UP",
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:36:37.000Z"),
    "uptime" : 221.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8ce9d18efa15b6d2fc0181"),
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "servico" : "fws_server.py",
    "diahora" : "86d 4h",
    "uptime" : 86.0,
    "status" : "UP",
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:37:37.000Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8ce9d18efa15b6d2fc0186"),
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "servico" : "pra_assy_server",
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:36:36.000Z"),
    "uptime" : 221.0,
    "diahora" : "221d 12h",
    "status" : "UP"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8ce9d28efa15b6d2fc018c"),
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "servico" : "pra_record_server",
    "status" : "UP",
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:37:37.000Z"),
    "diahora" : "221d 12h",
    "uptime" : 221.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8ce9d38efa15b6d2fc0190"),
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "servico" : "res_server",
    "status" : "UP",
    "diahora" : "221d 12h",
    "uptime" : 221.0,
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:37:37.000Z")
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8ce9d38efa15b6d2fc0194"),
    "instancia" : "bat1",
    "servico" : "seq_file_server",
    "status" : "UP",
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-26T13:37:37.000Z"),
    "diahora" : "221d 12h",
    "uptime" : 221.0
}
```

Comment: @srinivasy the first one works very well, of course, I did a match just to reduce the problem scope. Thank you for you help :-)